# Woocommerce Ajax Filtering - Product attributes via Range Slider

Tags: ajax, filter, woocommerce

I'm a little confused on how to get this working. Simply put, I want to replicate the functionality found here: http://codenegar.com/woocommerce-ajax-product-filter/shop/

Specifically, I want the ability to filter products using a range slider -- just like price -- but with my own custom attributes.

- I've looked into using the [YITH WooCommerce Ajax Navigation](https://wordpress.org/plugins/yith-woocommerce-ajax-navigation/) plugin -- but it only allows lists, colors, and dropdowns (no range sliders)
- This [codenegar plugin](http://codenegar.com/woocommerce-ajax-product-filter/) is exactly what I want -- but it seems it's no longer available for purchase.
- I also looked at the default [Layered Navigation Widget](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/woocommerce-widgets/) -- but to no avail.

What gives? Is there any commercially available plugin I can use?

For what it's worth -- I'm using the [Sistina theme](http://demo.yithemes.com/sistina/all-products/) from http://yithemes.com/

Thanks! -Josh

Answer (score 2):

You can try this one - https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-ajax-filters/
It is well supported and updates are often.

Features:

- No reloading, only ajax
- Slider, radio or checkbox
- No spamming with widgets in admin, 1 widget - multiple instances
- Filter visibility by product category. Different categories pages = different ( + global ) filters. One shop for everything
- Filter box height limit with scroll themes
- Working great with custom widget area
- Unlimited filters by product attributes

Comment: Just a point of clarity, the FREE version doesn't do range sliding of product attribute numbers, that's only in the Premium version. Which BeRocket should have mentioned, since they're the developers of that plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also looking for this plugin, I think it will have to be built manually.

This looks like something similar, however there is no demo, so we cant be sure it does what it says.

http://www.diczo.com/product/woocommerce-ajax-product-filter-wordpress-plugin